How to retain more data in prometheus
I've started Prometheus with
--storage.tsdb.retention.time=30d and --storeage.tsdb.retention.size=200GB.  If I check the status page, I see
Storage retention      30d or 200GiB

so I know the config has taken effect.   Unfortunately, I'm still only retaining 15d worth of data.  If did a du -h of the data dir and it's only taking up 125GB, so it shouldn't be limited by the size.  What else do I need to do to get Prometheus to retain more data?
